# MySQL return 0 for null responses

Tags: mysql

I have a mySQL request that looks like so:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS cnt,
    (3595 *
        acos(
            cos(radians({$lat1}))
            * cos(radians(lattitude))
            * cos(radians(longitude) - radians({$lon1}))
            + sin(radians({$lat1}))
            * sin(radians(lattitude))
        )
    ) AS distance,
    status
FROM
    members
WHERE 
    status in ('married', 'single', 'divorced')
GROUP BY
    status
HAVING 
    distance < 50
```

This is called by my AJAX request, which is done like this, for example:

```
success: function(data){
$("#count_marriedpeople").html(data[0].cnt);}
```

There are a few problems with this code. The values `{$lat1}` and `{$lon1}` correspond with input values. The idea is to tally all people within 50 miles from a given lattitude and longitude coordinate.

The problem I am having now is that if the result does not match EVERYTHING in the criteria, I get an unmatched error, and all my requests fail.

I have tried performing a `SELECT IF ISNULL`, but the problem (to my understanding) is that the code gives an empty result, not `null`. Thus, an `IFNULL` fallback would not work.

How might I fix this code so that if either `married`, `single`, or `divorced` do not have any values, then they simply return a 0, without ruining my query?

Comment: The database won't make things up. You need to have a table you can `JOIN` against which has these values in it if you want to force counts.

Comment: You can use `status IS NULL OR status IN ('married', 'single', 'divorced')`

Comment: Why do you allow null status in the first place?

Comment: What other values of `status` do you have? Why don't you just leave out the `WHERE` clause if you want all statuses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One big problem... the query doesn't "tally the number of people within 50 miles". The value returned for the `distance` expression is for a *single* row in the group. The condition in the `HAVING` clause is being applied to that one value.

To answer the question you asked... you need a *rowsource* that provides the status to be returned when there are no rows that match.

As an example of an approach to returning the specified result, something like this:

```
 SELECT s.status
      , COUNT(m.status) AS cnt
   FROM ( SELECT _latin1'married' AS status
          UNION ALL SELECT _latin1'single'
          UNION ALL SELECT _latin1'divorced'
        ) s
   LEFT     
   JOIN members m
     ON m.status = s.status
    AND (3595 *
        ACOS(
            COS(RADIANS({ $lat1 }))
            * COS(RADIANS(m.lattitude))
            * cos(radians(m.longitude) - RADIANS({ $lon1 }))
            + SIN(RADIANS({ $lat1 }))
            * SIN(RADIANS(m.lattitude))
        )
        ) < 50
  GROUP BY s.status
```

The inline view `s` returns three rows, the three values of status we want to return.

The *outer join* to `members` returns any "matching" rows. The conditions are in the `ON` clause of the outer join, not the WHERE clause.

The GROUP BY to collapse the rows, and get the COUNT aggregate.

This is an example of just one possible pattern.

There are other query patterns that will return an equivalent result.